# How to make sure that by default all points are initially in the 2D array in C?

Tags: c, turtle-graphics

I was doing my homework when I ran into a problem. The meaning of the program is that I set the size of a 2d array, then I write the directions in which the "turtle" will move, then the program outputs it. But when I run the program, even without instructions, the terminal outputs the following for me, for example

[image]

I can't figure out what my mistake is, by default the program should write

[image]

without that `o' at the beginning, how can I fix it?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int hor;
    int vert;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int i;
    int a;
    char symbol = 'z';
    scanf("%d%d", &vert, &hor);
    char* pole = (char*)malloc(vert * hor * sizeof(char));
    for (i = 0; i < vert; i++)
    {
        for(a = 0; a < hor; a++)
            pole[i * vert + a] = '.';
    }
    
    pole[x *vert + y] = 'o';
        
    while(symbol != 'x')
    {
        scanf("%c", &symbol);  
        if (symbol == '^') x--; 
        
        else if (symbol == 'v') x++; 
        else if (symbol == '>') y++; 
        else if (symbol == '<') y--; 
        else if (symbol == 'o') pole[x *vert + y] = 'o'; 
        
        if(y < 0)
            y = vert - 1; 
        else if(y > vert)
            y = 0;
        
        if(x < 0)
            x = hor - 1;
        else if(x > hor)
            x = 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < vert; i++)
    {
        for(a = 0; a < hor; a++)
        {
            printf("%c", pole[i *vert + a]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(pole);
    return 0;    
}
```

I tried to remove the "o", but nothing helped me:(

Comment: Don't you suppose that the `pole[x *vert + y] = 'o'` performed right after filling the array with `'.'` characters has something to do with it?

Comment: OT: UI suggestion for users with numeric keypad on the keyboard: Using 2, 4, 6 & 8 for the direction control characters would make life an awful lot easier...

Comment: AFAICT, remove `pole[x *vert + y] = 'o';` after the init loops

Comment: @JohnBollinger THANK YOU VERY MUCH! It works right, have a good evening! <3

Comment: @Fe2O3 Thank you for your suggestion, it's true, I'll do it!